# What is an overview of moral theories in Christianity?

Tags: morality, good-and-evil, ethics

What is an overview of moral theories in Christianity? From my own research, I know of at least three:

1. [Divine Command Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_command_theory). Wikipedia presents the following summary:

> Divine command theory (also known as theological voluntarism) is a meta-ethical theory which proposes that an action's status as morally good is equivalent to whether it is commanded by God. The theory asserts that what is moral is determined by God's commands and that for a person to be moral he is to follow God's commands. Followers of both monotheistic and polytheistic religions in ancient and modern times have often accepted the importance of God's commands in establishing morality.

2. [Divine Motivation Theory](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4020-8265-8_1523), by Linda Zagzebski. Here is an excerpt from the paper:

> Divine Motivation Theory (DMT) is a form of
> theologically based moral theory proposed by
> Linda Zagzebski. The theory defines all moral
> properties of persons, acts, and outcomes of acts
> in terms of God’s motives. God’s motives are
> states such as love and compassion, states that
> are motivating, and that are emotions or similar to
> emotions. She proposes that these states constitute the metaphysical and conceptual basis for
> moral value. Given traditional assumptions
> about the nature of God, the theory combines
> moral realism with divine noncognitivism.
>
> According to DMT, persons and their qualities
> are good in so far as they are like God or imitate God
> in the relevant respect. Human motives are good in
> so far as they are like the divine motives as those
> motives would be expressed in finite and embodied
> beings. Human virtues are those traits that imitate
> God’s virtues as they would be expressed by human
> beings in human circumstances. Outcomes get their
> moral value by their relation to good and bad motivations. For example, a state of affairs is a merciful one or a compassionate one or a just one because the
> divine motives that are constituents of mercy, compassion, and justice respectively aim at bringing them about. Acts get their moral value from the
> acts that would, would not, or might be done by a being who imitates God in the relevant circumstances. God’s own goodness and the rightness of
> God’s own acts follow immediately from the theory
> since God himself is the supreme standard of all
> moral value

3. [Christian Hedonism](https://www.desiringgod.org/topics/christian-hedonism), by John Piper, which to me sounds a bit like a Christianized version of Utilitarianism:

> Christian Hedonism is the conviction that God’s ultimate goal in the world (his glory) and our deepest desire (to be happy) are one and the same, because God is most glorified in us when we are most satisfied in him. Not only is God the supreme source of satisfaction for the human soul, but God himself is glorified by our being satisfied in him. Therefore, our pursuit of joy in him is essential.
>
> Christian Hedonism claims that the Christian life should be the pursuit of maximum joy in God — joy both in quality and quantity. Fullness of joy and joy forevermore (Psalm 16:11) are found only in him.

Are there other moral theories in Christianity?

Comment: Why do you think Christian Hedonism is a "moral theory"? I don't think John Piper describes it as that.

Comment: @DJClayworth Because it sounds very similar to a Christianized version of [Utilitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism), where the goal is maximization of utility (usually happiness and well-being).

Comment: @Mark You're forgetting the Christian version of [Natural law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_law) moral theory developed to maturity by Thomas Aquinas who in his *Summa Theologica* ties it to spiritual happiness and virtues, thus linking moral theory and "Christian hedonism": the pleasure of doing what is right and loving based on objective criteria.  I think C.S. Lewis, a medievalist, adopted this view also, and in the 21st century picked up by his many followers, including John Piper.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Would you like to post an answer explaining that view?

Comment: @Mark Sure, but I'm rather busy this week.  That theory has very solid and long pedigree and is my personal favorite.  I believe the Catholic church still wholeheartedly adopts it as the framework for sexual ethics, social ethics, her own internal canon law, etc. although among her theologians there are new modern theories being considered.  You may find other less known moral theories (especially modern ones) by reading through the *Wikipedia* article [Christian Ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_ethics).  The Divine Motivation Theory is new to me, but looks interesting!

Comment: Are you asking what Jesus of Nazareth taught ? . . . . .   when you say 'theories' ?

Comment: @NigelJ Well, if only a single way of interpreting the Bible existed, then I would agree. Unfortunately, each denomination has their own views and theories.

Comment: So you are not seeking the actual teachings of Jesus Christ and his own chosen apostles. You are seeking the divergent misunderstandings of less than perfect followers. Have I understood this aright ?

Comment: @NigelJ Does what you just said apply to you? Or are you the exception to the rule? Because if not, whatever you say would also be part of the "divergent misunderstandings of less than perfect followers". Why are we even wasting our time in this forum in the first place if whatever anyone says is a "misunderstanding"?

Comment: The fact is that truth has been revealed. _The_ Truth. (Singular.)

Comment: To Mark and to @NigelJ Yes Jesus (the Truth) has been revealed.  But Jesus didn't reveal everything. Trinity came later, for example, and there are other theological truths to be discovered in light of new human conditions and experience and culture. Science, technology, and human history create new questions that Bible didn't answer directly, thus Biblical moral theory needs development. The responsible way is to START from what's available of the witness about Jesus & apostles THEN try to reflect on and establish truths that are "downstream" from Scripture to fill where Scripture is silent.